# Why are there numbers after the question mark in some JS/CSS URLs?

Tags: javascript, css

Why do use like this filename.css?2 or filename.js?4 
What are those numbers after question mark?

I did research online but I didn't find any answer.

Thanks!

Comment: It is revision numbers or cache busters as listed below. When people release a new version of their javascript, they increment this by one to force people to grab the latest version of their JS.

Comment: You say you did research online, yet when I copy/paste the first line of your question into Google, we get the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044085/what-does-used-after-javascript-filename-means Odd.

Answer (score 7):

These are called cache busters.

Usually, when a browser downloads a file (CSS, JS, etc.) it caches it so that it doesn't have to download it later.

However, this is a problem when you decide to update your file, because the browser thinks it already has the latest version. To work around it, we use the cache busters. When you make a change to the file, you also change the number after the question marks, which tricks the browser into thinking this is a different file for which it doesn't have a cache it, and forces a re-download.

Comment: I opposed why did this answer got upvotes???? Wrong information!!!!

Comment: @C-link Nepal, mind telling what is wrong?

Comment: Please read double times your answer and duplicate answers marked in the question...

Comment: They say pretty much what I said. So, again, do you mind pointing **exactly** what is wrong?

Comment: The point you're giving is wrong like `it caches it so that it doesn't have to download it later.` but we use it for latest file download....

Comment: That's what caching is for, I believe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60853/discussion-between-raphael-and-c-link-nepal).

Comment: We use query selector to remove cache but not to apply cache...!

Comment: If you read carefully, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: Still, you've wrong point. remove `it caches it so that it doesn't have to download it later.` and then it will be fine...

Comment: But that's what it does. I'm not saying it is because of the cache buster, I'm simply saying the browser does it. I'd recommend you read it more carefully.

Comment: NO, it doesn't, you may try yourself by using query selector and then changing your css file again and do clean refresh, it will show you latest or cached file???? The answer latest.....

Comment: OK, you clearly can't interpret what I'm saying. Never mind then.

Comment: Am I missunderstanding your answer, Sorry then. I'll remove my -1 (As nice guy of you [having peace talks]). (but still you should try to understand that cache the file or clear the cache...)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes JS scripts are created on the fly using server side technologies other times it is simply a version number to help with browser caching issues